# Не работает анимация после изменения классов

Tags: javascript, html, css

Возникла проблема с анимацией. Есть такой toolbar в котором есть кнопка раскрытия/скрытия. Через js менял классы самому svg, а также всей кнопке. При наведении на кнопку она подымается или опускается (в зависимости от того в каком направлении расположена иконка). При первом нажатии анимация работает корректно, при втором и последующих уже не работает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Draft</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="draft.css">

</head>

<body>
<div class="sidebar toolbar">
    <div class="open toolbar-btn">
        <img src="../img/icons/chevron.svg" alt="Open" class="chevron chevron-down" draggable="false">
    </div>

    <div class="font toolbar-btn">
        <img src="../img/icons/font.svg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="underline toolbar-btn">
        <img src="../img/icons/underline.svg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="italic toolbar-btn">
        <img src="../img/icons/italic.svg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="color toolbar-btn">
        <img src="../img/icons/color.svg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="resize toolbar-btn">
        <img src="../img/icons/resize.svg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="download toolbar-btn">
        <img src="../img/icons/download.svg" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="empty"></div>

    <div class="lock toolbar-btn">
        <img src="../img/icons/lock.svg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@import "../css/nullstyle";

$scroll-color: linear-gradient(180deg, #A00BC5 0%, #1B5454 100%);
$scroll-color-hover: linear-gradient(180deg, #D012FF 0%, #0B9191 100%);
$panels-color: linear-gradient(90deg, #161616 -23.12%, #262525 100%);

.open, .hide {
  transition: transform 300ms;

  &:hover {
    .chevron-down {
      transform: translateY(7px);
    }

    .chevron-up {
      transform: translateY(-7px);
    }
  }

  .chevron {
    transition: inherit;
  }
}

.toolbar {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: $panels-color;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;

  transition: height 300ms;

  .toolbar-btn, .empty {
    display: grid;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
  }
}
```

JS

```
let chevronFromToolbar = document.querySelector('.toolbar-btn > .chevron');
let toolbar =  document.querySelector('.toolbar');

let chevronFromSaves = document.querySelector('.saves-btn > .chevron');
function rotateChevron (chevron, degrees) {
        chevron.style.transform = `rotate(${degrees}deg)`;
}

toolbar.firstElementChild.onclick = () => {
    if (toolbar.firstElementChild.classList.contains('open')) {
        toolbar.style.height = '720px';
        toolbar.firstElementChild.style.order = '8 ';
        chevronFromToolbar.classList.remove('chevron-down');
        chevronFromToolbar.classList.add('chevron-up');

        rotateChevron(chevronFromToolbar, 180);

        toolbar.firstElementChild.classList.remove('open');
        toolbar.firstElementChild.classList.add('hide');
    }
    else if (toolbar.firstElementChild.classList.contains('hide')) {
        toolbar.style.height = '80px';
        toolbar.firstElementChild.style.order = '0';
        chevronFromToolbar.classList.remove('chevron-up');
        chevronFromToolbar.classList.add('chevron-down');

        rotateChevron(chevronFromToolbar, 360);

        toolbar.firstElementChild.classList.remove('hide');
        toolbar.firstElementChild.classList.add('open');
    }
};
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не убираются отступы между grid элементами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1472369/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-grid-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Answer (score 0):

Вызов функции `rotateChevron` переопределяет стили прописывая их инлайново в разметке, а именно свойство `transform`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отказаться от использования функции `rotateChevron` и логику переворота возложить на css. Вы уже добавляете определённый класс `.chevron-up`, поэтому можно просто дописать стиль

```
.open,
.hide {
  transition: transform 300ms;

  &:hover {
    .chevron-down {
      transform: translateY(7px);
    }

    .chevron-up {
      transform: translateY(-7px);
    }
  }

  .chevron {
    transition: inherit;

    &.chevron-up {
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
  }
}
```

Чтобы ховер для шеврона работал и при раскрытом меню,меняя его положение, можно добавить веса селектору и добавив ту же самую трансформацию

```
.open,
.hide {
  transition: transform 300ms;

  &:hover {
    .chevron-down {
      transform: translateY(7px);
    }

    .chevron.chevron-up {
      transform: rotate(180deg) translateY(7px);
    }
  }

  .chevron {
    transition: inherit;

    &.chevron-up {
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Можете подсказать каким способом это можно исправить?

Comment: Отказаться от использования функции `rotateChevron` и логику переворота возложить на css. Вы уже добавляете определённый класс `.chevron-up`, поэтому можно просто дописать стиль 

    `&.chevron-up {
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
  `

Comment: Вообще это хорошая практика, когда стили применяются при совмещении определённых классов. Например есть меню с классом `.menu` и при клике через js добавляем ему класс `.is-open`. Получается у элемента теперь 2 класса `menu is-open`. А в css уже прописано для просто класса `.menu` свои стили, а для `.menu.is-open` другие, типа поменять цвет самое простое или как в вашем случае сделать transform. Кстати для анимаций лучше всего использовать `transform` или `opacity` так как это не так сильно нагружает браузер. Об этом: [https://doka.guide/js/how-the-browser-creates-pages/#cpu-i-kompoziting]

Comment: Можно ли вас побеспокоить ещё одним вопросом? Буду благодарен, если снова поможете. При такой записи, как указали вы начало работать лучше. Если раскрыть, потом свернуть: translateY работает, до этого не работал, но это же свойство не работает, когда тулбар открыт, при этом .chevron переворачивается. Если убрать эту запись:
&.chevron-up {
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
То translateY начинает работать, но логично: chevron перестает переворачиваться. Я так понимаю это из-за перезаписи свойства transform, пытался менять порядок записи, но до правильного решения не догадался.

Comment: Добавил вариант в ответ. Также рекомендую более детально разобраться в понятие специфичность css селекторов: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity